# Qt UIThreadWidget

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, thread-safety

I have the code:

```
void ChildThread::run()
{
  pUIThreadWidget->fun();
}

void UIThreadWidget::fun()
{
  emit Signal();
}

void UIThreadWidget::Slot()
{
  //operations about UI
}

UIThreadWidget::UIThreadWidget()
{
  connect(this, SIGNAL(void), this, SLOT(void));
}
```

`pUIThreadWidget` is a pointer to `UIThreadWidget`.

I get a warning "*QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread*," but no errors and my program does not crash. My question is, is this code thread-safe?

Comment: Nah, those warnings telling you that it's not safe ... they don't mean anything.

Comment: This code is created by my colleague.I told him about what you said.However,because of little errors or crash,he didn't believe me.

Answer (score 3):

**QPixmap** is display-dependent is designed and optimized for showing images on screen.

It accesses the underlying graphics system. Most graphics systems are not thread-safe. So hence the warning.

Try using **QImage**.

Comment: This is the correct solution, you can work with a `QImage` in a worker thread, then pass it back to the GUI thread and convert it to a `QPixmap`.

Comment: Althought this is not what I want abouy,your suggestion is very important for my future.Thanks!